# How to store previous result into a var

Tags: javascript

Pretty new to Javascript..

I have managed to script this simple code here:

```
var currentstock = 50;

function stockminus(x){
    newcurrent = currentstock - x;
    return newcurrent;
};
console.log(stockminus(10));
```

the output of this must be : `40`

How can I store that new output into `currentstock` as the new value or in other words overwrite that var?

so next time I call that function again, output should be : `30`
Becasue the new currentstock is `40` from the previous call

Answer (score 2):

Simple, `currentstock = stockminus(10)`

Comment: any idea how I would reset it? back to 50?

Answer (score 2):

The [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

So, every time you are working in the same scope you can do:

```js
let currentstock = 50;

function stockminus(x) {
  return currentstock -= x;
};


console.log(stockminus(10));
console.log(stockminus(10));
```

Comment: Hi Yosvel! what does `let` do? first time I have seen this

Comment: @Eduards i have improved the answer and added link to `let` documentation.. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var stockDetails = (function(initialValue){
  var currentStock = initialValue;
  return {
    getCurrentStock: function() {
       return currentStock;
    },
    stockminus: function(x) {
       //add additional logic to check negative cases
       currentStock-= x;
       return currentStock;
    }
 }
})(50);
```

you can use this type of modular patterns to access data using methods and later extend it as per needs.

access it like

```
stockDetails.getCurrentStock();
stockDetails.stockminus(10);
```